# FIWARE Orion - Error: "Response to QueryContext is empty"

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have followed the **NGSI API** documentation and I'm using registrations to forward a query to a custom path which will handle it.

I'm working on the examples shown in the **APIv2** Documentation. I have two containers running the Context broker on different ports.

In one of them I have created the Room1 asset, in the other I have created the registration for that asset.

I'm querying the second one for that identity, in the logs the following message appears:

```
orion2_1  | time=Friday 02 Nov 08:48:19 2018.704Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=postQueryContext.cpp[168]:queryForward | msg=Other Error (context provider response to QueryContext is empty)
```

#### This is the registration:

```
{
    "id": "5bdc14dfcbe7f9fb0a95002e",
    "description": "Registration for Room1",
    "dataProvided": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": "Room1",
                "type": "Room"
            }
        ],
        "attrs": [
            "temperature",
            "pressure"
        ]
    },
    "provider": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://192.168.1.100:8000/v2"
        },
        "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
        "legacyForwarding": true
    },
    "status": "active"
}
```

#### This is the **Room1** entity:

```
{
    "id": "Room1",
    "type": "Room",
    "pressure": {
        "type": "Integer",
        "value": 720,
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "temperature": {
        "type": "Float",
        "value": 23,
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include the exact query (I mean, the REST request) you are doing, please? Thanks!

Comment: It was actually solved by Fran de la Vega. The issue was related with the API I'm implementing: I needed to add a path with /queryContext, to which the Ctx Broker forwards the request. Please try to improve the documentation with examples or something clearer, as the deprecated v1 of the API is still online.

Comment: Good to know it was solved :) It would be great if you could self-answer your question, so other future users with similar problems know the solution.Thanks!

Comment: Which regards to documentation improvements, could you provide the link(s) to the document(s) that should be clarified? Thanks!